# How to draw vertical arrows at the left and right to my list in beamer slide

Tags: beamer

I have a simplie slide with a list of items.
I would like to draw an increasing (vertical) arrow with some text inside (or below) at the left of my list, and a decreasing at the right of my list, like on the example attached. 
My frame is defined as:

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Is there a simple solution to draw arrows?}

\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]

 \item Politics

 \item Empirical

 \item Simplified mechanistic 

 \item Full dynamics

\end{itemize}
```

Many thanks for your help!
[image: example made with...ppt...]

Comment: Welcome! Please can you complete your code so we can compile it? You might look at `tikzmark`, though it may be overkill.

Comment: thank you cfr, sorry, I should have put the whole code, I will know it for next time!

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.arrows}

    \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Is there a simple solution to draw arrows?}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
SA/.style = {single arrow, draw=blue!40!gray, very thick, fill=blue!20!gray!10,
             minimum height=1.6*\n1,
            }       
                    ]
\node (n)   [text width=0.8\textwidth]
{
    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
\item Politics
\item Empirical
\item Simplified mechanistic
\item Full dynamics
    \end{itemize}
};
\path   let \p1 = ($(n.north)-(n.south)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\x1)} in
        node[SA, rotate=90,  xshift=\n1/2,
             above=of n.south west] {Easy to apply}
        node[SA, rotate=-90,  xshift=-\n1/2,
             above=of n.south east] {Transparency};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, itemize is put in `tikz` node, for arrows are used `single arrow` shape.

**Addendum:**
arrows are accommodate to itemize height (actually 1.6 times of it). This I selected due to two reasons:

- text in arrows is longer than itemize height,
- from provided picture I (now seems wrongly) conclude, that this is desired

In MWE below I reduce arrows height to approximately height of text in itemize and change font size (to `\large` in `itemize` environment and to `\small` in arrows. Also to be both arrows equal tall I replace `minimum width` with `text width`. Result of those changes are:

[image]

and corrected code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.arrows}

    \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Is there a simple solution to draw arrows?}

    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
SA/.style = {single arrow, draw=blue!40!gray, very thick, fill=blue!20!gray!10,
            inner xsep=0pt, text width=\n1-4ex, align=center,% 4ex compensate vertical space above and below itemize
            font=\small
            }       
                    ]

\node (n)   [text width=0.8\textwidth, font=\large]
{
    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
\item Politics
\item Empirical
\item Simplified mechanistic
\item Full dynamics
    \end{itemize}
};
\path   let \p1 = ($(n.north)-(n.south)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\x1)} in
        node[SA, rotate=90,  xshift=0.45*\n1,
             above=of n.south west] {Easy to apply}
        node[SA, rotate=-90,  xshift=-0.55*\n1,
             above=of n.south east] {Transparency};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: ok, this is very good! the only thing is that they are not adpated to the size of the my list, but I can understand what is doing tikz (which I never used, being a basic beamer user). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Clir You can say e.g. `above=0pt of <shape>` if you don't want the arrows to extend beyond the list.

Comment: The arrow size is adopted to list size, however from your figure is seams that they should be taller ... so I multiply the height of your list with `1.6`. This can be reduced and also considered @cfr suggestion. I will add this option to my answer.

Comment: ok, the code does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help (and so fast!)

Comment: Zarko calls \usepgflibrary{shapes.arrows} though Percusse is calling \usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.arrows} , is there a difference between usetikz and usepgf?

Comment: Do you mess names? I use libraries `calc`, `positioning` and  `shapes.arrows` and @biajia (Percusse only edit answer) only `shapes.arrows`. Difference is essential. Library `calc` is used for measure `itemize` environments height (actually node in which it is), `positioning` for placement of arrows. Solution of biajia has different (less sophisticated) approach, so he/she doesn't need other libraries.

Comment: @Clir It is better to use `\usetikzlibrary` as the TikZ version sometimes defines wrappers which may be unexpectedly absent from the lower level PGF version of the library. (And sometimes there is no PGF library of the same name.)

Comment: ok thank you very much to you 2, I know understand the difference. And I also understand that there is on this great forum somebody who edits and somebody who answers, sorry for the names !

Answer (score 2):

Using the following codes can get the effects as what you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{my arrow} = [draw=cyan!75, very thick, single arrow, minimum height=7.5cm, shape border rotate =#1, fill=gray!10]`

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Is there a simple solution to draw arrows?}
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]

    \item Politics \tikz \coordinate (po);

    \item Empirical

    \item Simplified mechanistic 

    \item Full dynamics

\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node at (-0.25,1) [my arrow=90] {\rotatebox{90}{Easy to apply}};
\node at (10,1) [my arrow=-180] {\rotatebox{-90}{Transparency}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the coordinate do? Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: @cfr, what do you mean by deprecated?

Comment: ok this is good, except the arrows don't have the size of the list, so I have a preference for Zarko answer. However, I had never used tikz but I see with your example that this is not so difficult as expected. thank you very much!

Comment: you call \usepgflibrary{shapes.arrows} though Zarko is calling \usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.arrows} ,

Comment: @Clir Deprecated: ought not be used in new code; recommended not to be used in new code. It still works, but is best avoided. (At some point, deprecated macros can disappear, depending on the authors' policies etc.)

Comment: @Clir Yes, when using TikZ, it is better to use \usetikzlibrary.